# Add link to function in InfoWindow without overriding 'Zoom to' - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to see if there is a way to add a link in the InfoWindow that fires a function in JavaScript. I'm working with a map that shows rail lines in the US and the idea is to store selected lines in an array to collect information.

I know that you can override the 'Zoom To' link with `dojo.disconnect(map.infoWindow._eventConnections[4])` to replace the zoom action with your own, but I do not want to sacrifice this function. I would use `.setContent()` and add the link to the function using HTML, but because I'm using `.setFeatures()`, this would remove information about the feature currently selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the ArcGIS-JS-API 3.X. 
You have check the Popup class, and add a new action using the [addActions(actions)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#addactions) Method.

For example:

```
  var customActions;

  map.infoWindow.on("selection-change", function() {
    var selectedFeature = map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature();

    if (selectedFeature && selectedFeature.attributes.TYPE === "crime") {
      var crimeAction = {
        title: "Crime Report",
        className: "crime-report-action",
        callback: function() {
          console.log("Get Full Crime Report");
        }
      };
      customActions = map.infoWindow.addActions([ crimeAction ]);
    }
    else {
      map.infoWindow.removeActions(customActions);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.2. I keep on forgetting that there's 4.X because it's 3D only at the moment. This seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Check out the new 4.X... it isn't only 3D!